# how to dismiss drupal supported version alert

Tags: drupal-8, php-7.4

I have hosting with php 7.4 and Drupal 8.9.20.
In admin section I have alert that drupal is old.
Drupal 9 support only php 8 and I can't update server, hosting supports only 7.4.
How to remove this alert? it's always apear (

Answer (score 0):

Drupal 9  Supports PHP 7.4 but the recommended PHP version is 8.0 or higher recommended. Check below documentation for a clear idea.

[Drupal - PHP requirements](https://www.drupal.org/docs/system-requirements/php-requirements)

You can disable *update notifications* by disabling the **Update Manager** module, which is responsible for checking and informing about available updates.

Navigate to Extend -> Search for "Update Manager" and disable the module.

[image: Disable Update Manager module]

This is not recommended but you can keep this module enabled in your development environment and know when a security updates are released.

Drupal 10 is around the corner and it only supports PHP 8.1 and above. You should better migrate to a different hosting provider as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Since June, the release of Drupal core 9.4.0 has now brought a new permission which allows disabling of these alerts and not needing to uninstall the module, very cool right? :)

https://www.drupal.org/node/3280750